# Alter views style using regenerate feature?

Tags: 7, features

I created a views using feature and export the views in my second site. After some time I need to change in views style. After change in style I regenerate the feature and export again.

I disabled the previous version and enable this version. The changes in fields are altered but changes of styles plugin are not altered. I cleared the cache and also uninstalled and installed again, but it didn't work at all.

Anyone used feature module like this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to enable / disable features on prod server after uploading the new files

First, on your prod site clear all the caches

Then go on the view's page `admin/structure/views` click on the dropdown list beside your view, you should have an operation 'revert' : that's it

If you dont have 'revert' operation, (and disable is present) it means the views is up to date with your feature's file

Of course, the start point is to re-export your feature's files from your local site and upload them to your server (do not export/import your view, the code must be in the feature's files)

Comment: Yes, but how can I say this to client? Is there no other method?